# Modulus Summation

Tags: code-golf, sequence, division

I call this sequence "the Jesus sequence", because it is the *sum of mod*.</pun>

For this sequence, you take all the positive integers *m* less than the input *n*, and take the sum of *n* modulo each *m*. In other words:

$$a_n = \sum_{m=1}^{n-1}{n\bmod m}$$

For example, take the term *14*:

```
14 % 1 = 0
14 % 2 = 0
14 % 3 = 2
14 % 4 = 2
14 % 5 = 4
14 % 6 = 2
14 % 7 = 0
14 % 8 = 6
14 % 9 = 5
14 % 10 = 4
14 % 11 = 3
14 % 12 = 2
14 % 13 = 1
0+0+2+2+4+2+0+6+5+4+3+2+1=31
```

Your goal here is to write a function that implements this sequence. You should take the sequence term (this will be a positive integer from 1 to 2<sup>31</sup>) as the only input, and output the value of that term. This is [OEIS A004125](https://oeis.org/A004125).

As always, [standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/62402) apply and the shortest answer in bytes wins!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

```
L%O
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fR9X//39DEwA)

Answer (score 10):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 22 bytes

```hs
f x=sum$mod x<$>[1..x]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P02hwra4NFclNz9FocJGxS7aUE@vIvZ/bmJmnoKtQnpqiXN@XklqXkmxgp2drUJBUWZeiYKeQhoQF6Umpvw3NAEA)

#### Explanation

Yes.

Comment: Great explanation

Answer (score 8):

## [Funky](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/Funky), 25 bytes

```
n=>fors=~-i=1i<n)s+=n%i++
```

Just the Naïve answer, seems to work.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyvNy678n2b7P8/WLi2/qNi2TjfT1jDTJk@zWNs2TzVTW/t/QVFmXolGmoahiabmfwA)

## [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator), 25 bytes.

```
f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^xmod(x,n)
```

Paste into Desmos, then run it by calling `f`.

When pasted into Desmos, the latex looks like this

[image]

The graph however looks like

[image]

Although it looks random and all over the place, that's the result of only supporting integers.

## [RProgN 2](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/RProgN-2), 9 bytes

```
x=x³x\%S+
```

### Explained

```
x=x³x\%S+
x=          # Store the input in "x"
  x         # Push the input to the stack.
   ³x\%     # Define a function which gets n%x
       S    # Create a stack from "x" with the previous function. Thus this gets the range from (1,x), and runs (i%x) on each element.
        +   # Get the sum of this stack.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kyooyk/P0zX6/7/CtuLQ5ooY1WDt////G5oAAA)

## [ReRegex](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/ReRegex), 71 bytes

```
#import math
(_*)_a$/d<$1_>b$1a/(\d+)b/((?#input)%$1)+/\+a//u<#input
>a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otSk1Prfj/XzkztyC/qEQhN7Ekg0sjXkszPlFFP8VGxTDeLknFMFFfIyZFWzNJX0PDXjkzr6C0RFNVxVBTWz9GO1Ffv9QGIsZll/j/v6EJAA)

## [ARBLE](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/ARBLE), 19 bytes

```lua
sum(range(1,a)|a%i)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyxKykn9/7@4NFejKDEvPVXDUCdRsyZRNVPz////hiYA)

## [MaybeLater](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/MaybeLater), 56 bytes

```
whenf is*{n=0whenx is*{ifx>0{n=n+f%x x--}elseprintn}x=f}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y02sTErNSSxJLfr/vzwjNS9NIbNYqzrP1gDEqQBzMtMq7AyAQnnaaaoVChW6urWpOcWpBUWZeSV5tRW2abX/0xRsFTSKUhNTEjV1Df4bmgAA)

Comment: Will the submissions to this challenge ever end? So far I've been getting a new one every 40 minutes :P

Comment: @StephenLeppik Oh I've still got more coming, don't worry.

Comment: @StephenLeppik I'd rather not, because they're of various quality across various languages.

Comment: @StephenLeppik I've combined them for you, begrudgingly.

Comment: Thanks! Now you get an upvote because all this is lots of effort.

Comment: Please don't do this. Separate languages -- even separate approaches -- should go in separate answers.

Comment: @Dennis Although I agree with you, OP said to do it this way, so I've done it this way.

Answer (score 7):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>28</s> <s>27</s> 23 bytes

-4 bytes thanks to @daniero.

```ruby
->n{(1..n).sum{|i|n%i}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyflmf7X9cur1rDUE8vT1OvuDS3uiazJk81s7b2f4FCWl60oUnsfwA)

### Ruby, 28 bytes

```ruby
f=->n{n>($.+=1)?n%$.+f[n]:0}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P81W1y6vOs9OQ0VP29ZQ0z5PFchIi86LtTKo/V@gkBZtaBL7HwA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
%RS
```

**Explanation**

```
%RS
 R   Range(input)  [1...n]
%    Input (implicit) modulo [1...n]->[n%1,n%2...n%n]
  S  Sum of the above
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/181KPj///@GJgA)

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 4 bytes

```
t:\s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/v8Qqpvj/f0MTAA)

Explanation:

```
t      % Duplicate input. Stack: {n, n}
 :     % Range 1...n. Stack: {n, [1...n]}
  \    % Modulo. Stack: {[0,0,2,2,4,...]}
   s   % Sum. Implicitly display result.
```

Answer (score 5):

## R, 20 bytes

```
sum((n=scan())%%1:n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v7g0V0Mjz7Y4OTFPQ1NTVdXQKk/zv6HJ//8A)

Answer (score 4):

## [Ohm v2](https://github.com/nickbclifford/Ohm), 4 bytes

```
D@%Σ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8/INfr/38VB9dzi//8NTQA)

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 5 bytes

```apl
+/⍳|⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R2wRt/Ue9m2sedS0Ccg@tALKNDAA)

**How?**

Monadic train -

`+/` - sum

`⊢` - `n`

`|` - vectorized modulo

`⍳` - the range of `n`

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 44 bytes

```python
lambda n:sum(map(lambda x:x%(n-x),range(n)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcgxCoAwDAXQ3VP8RUiggjoWvIlLRauCjaVWiKevg77xxSdvp/TFYxjL4cI0O4i97kDBRfpDrdYkjbJJTtaFhJmLPxMUu@C7rm3ZVgBi2iVDDTwplxc)

EDIT: Changed range(0,n) to range(n)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the site! `range` implicitly takes a first argument of `0`, so you could shorten this by two bytes by doing `range(n)` instead.

Comment: Oh wow! I didn't even think of that. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! You can use a list comprehension instead of `map` for 38 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfpmAb8z8nMTcpJVEhz6q4NFejQlUjT7dCMy2/SKFCITNPoSgxLz1VI09T8z@akKGBgaYVl4KCQkFRZl6JQoWOQppGheZ/AA "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Comment: You are right, but that was used in Neil's answer, so I wasn't sure if copying it would have been the best thing. Unless I am missing something here of course. I wanted to post the alternative, even if it was a bit longer.

Answer (score 4):

## Rust, 27 characters

```rust
|n|(1..n).map(|i|n%i).sum()
```

Based on [Should rust anonymous functions fully specify parameter types?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25156/should-rust-anonymous-functions-fully-specify-parameter-types) I assume that return type inference is also fine.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LctNCoMwEEDhtZ5iKhRmQALRrio9TJAUBpJR8rNKPHsaqOv3vZBjal8Bb1iQyjg4m2B3R8zBwgdalYpaKSHlzYmVqzyZVMweqQ3bnwcbs0tv4HXpyz2jflHvZ2BJTh44lWuab9rD1X4)

Answer (score 4):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 16 bytes

```julia
~x=sum(x.%(1:x))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/v67Ctrg0V6NCT1XD0KpCU/N/dEFRZl5JTp5GTkFiikamjpGmjpKVgpIOmFuXqWOsqamQll@kkKmQmadgaGVoGvsfAA)

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 26 bytes

```js
f=(n,k=n)=>n&&k%n+f(n-1,k)
```

#### Demo

```js
f=(n,k=n)=>n&&k%n+f(n-1,k)

for(n = 1; n < 30; n++) {
  console.log('a(' + n + ') = ' + f(n))
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 37 bytes

```python
lambda a:sum(a%k for k in range(1,a))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHRqrg0VyNRNVshLb9IIVshM0@hKDEvPVXDUCdRU/M/SDARSdDAQNOKSwEICooy80o00pSqE2utFKrTNBI1a5U0/wMA)

Comment: 4 answers in 10 minutes? Wow.

Comment: Must be some very gifted programmers. ;)

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>6</s> 5 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to @Shaggy*

```
Æ%XÃx
```

[Test it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=xiVYw3g=&input=MTQ=)

#### How it works

```
         Implicit: U = input number
Æ        Create the range [0, U),
 %XÃ       mapping each item X to U%X. U%0 gives NaN.
    x    Sum, ignoring non-numbers.
         Implicit: output result of last expression
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 9 bytes

```
ＩΣＥＮ﹪Ｉθ⊕ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEI7g0V8M3sUDDM6@gtMSvNDcptUhDU8c3P6U0Jx@iolBTR1tbI1MTDKz//zc0@a9blgMA)

Link is to the verbose version of the code:

```
Print(Cast(Sum(Map(InputNumber(),Modulo(Cast(q),++(i))))));
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Standard ML (MLton)](http://www.mlton.org/), <s>53</s> 51 bytes

```ml
fn& =>let fun f 1a=a|f%a=f(% -1)(a+ &mod%)in f&0end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYsxC8IwFIT3/oqjkJIglUbdJN2dXUUJNE8K6YuYp5P/vcYu9qbv7vjyFNspSuL57SPIzcQNXB@DgF4MgvXOf0h5R1qhtUb7DZopDcqM5W66wMOiSsgCh8dzZEGCJkZ2fb7WF65NGU4sW0lnKf@9VKp@0q0YukLJotvjn3cr3q/YHtal68z8BQ)

**Ungolfed:**

```ml
fn n =>
   let fun f 1 a = a
         | f x a = f (x-1) (a + n mod x)
   in  
       f n 0
   end
```

---

#### Previous 53 byte version:

```ml
fn n=>foldl op+0(List.tabulate(n-1,fn i=>n mod(i+1)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYyxDgIhDIb3e4rmJsh5BtTNwG7i5mo0mDsMCZSLVF8f6y3S6fvb/2tJcUyRMtaPi@BN9QhorM9xipCXQYlzKLQl93hHR7PAUW@4EoxFSHkSYdBSylWmuRAYWF4BCTIIrhVjy62/Yi95cUL@ky/E9ydH3/2kOxuiA55V18c/7xreN6wPbVBK1i8)

**Explanation:**

`List.tabulate` takes an integer `x` and a function `f` and generates the list `[f 0, f 1, ..., f(x-1)]`. Given some number `n`, we call `List.tabulate` with `n-1` and the function `fn i=>n mod(i+1)` to avoid dividing by zero. The resulting list is summed with `foldl op+0`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 45 bytes

```java
n->{int m=n,s=0;for(;m-->1;)s+=n%m;return s;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU49a8MwFNz9K46Awa4/SLsqNnTMEDqETqWD6o8g13oS0nPABP92V07bqR0eB3f37m6QV1kY29HQfq5KW@MYQ@DKidVYPojoD@fZdVL/K/UTNawMbaKdPkbVoBml9zhJRbhFwA/rWXKAq1EtdNCSMztFl7d3SHfx6d0KHIlfSbr5xXZOsnHoUa1U1DdFDF1R7qu96I1LhC6K@lGkPqso1sJ1PDmCF8sq7kGbZ/tRqLAXAQ542jDLfquA8@y506WZuLRhC/fJLm5R1IjbmHY5VI6@lNaO87MPwxKVpt/hS7Tdsn4B)

Comment: +1 For using the goes to (`-->`) operator.

Answer (score 3):

## [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 18 bytes

```
#~Mod~i~Sum~{i,#}&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7X7nONz@lLrMuuDS3rjpTR7lW7X9AUWZeSXRatKFJbOx/AA)

Comment: same bytes `Tr[#~Mod~Range@#]&`

Answer (score 3):

## T-SQL, <s>80</s> 79 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to @MickyT*

```
WITH c AS(SELECT @ i UNION ALL SELECT i-1FROM c WHERE i>1)SELECT SUM(@%i)FROM c
```

Receives input from an integer parameter named `@`, something like this:

```
DECLARE @ int = 14;
```

Uses a Common Table Expression to generate numbers from `1` to `n`. Then uses that cte to sum up the moduluses.

Note: a cte needs a `;` between the previous statement and the cte. Most code I've seen puts the `;` right before the declaration, but in this case I can save a byte by having it in the input statement (since technically my code by itself is the only statement).

[Try it (SEDE)](https://data.stackexchange.com/codegolf/query/edit/770634)

---

The less "SQL-y" way is only 76 bytes. This time the input variable is `@i` instead of `@` (saves one byte). This one just does a `while` loop.

```
DECLARE @ int=2,@o int=0WHILE @<@i BEGIN SELECT @o+=@i%@,@+=1 END PRINT @o
```

Answer (score 3):

## [4](https://github.com/urielieli/py-four), 67 bytes

**4** doesn't have any *modulo* built in.

```
3.79960101002029980200300023049903204040310499040989804102020195984
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYo5DoBADAP7fUVWtAg5BxAX/Juaj4WAprBHmqjy7SQPaAODkdkDR5sjSLghGtffAsxOQr8Yyp0ZVXOMRaZc4r7Kc/fRjBc)

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 3 bytes

```
ɽ%∑
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C9%BD%25%E2%88%91&inputs=14&header=&footer=)

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `s`, 2 bytes

```
ɽ%
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=s&code=%C9%BD%25&inputs=14&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

```
ÎGIN%+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//cJ@7p5@q9v//ZkYA)

My first 05AB1E program ;)

<s>Btw I got two 39s, 1 for JS6 and 1 for python, but I was too late</s>

Explanation:

```
ÎGIN%+
Î                      # Push 0, then input, stack = [(accumulator = 0), I]
 G                     # For N in range(1, I), stack = [(accumulator)]
  IN                   # Push input, then N, stack = [(accumulator), I, N]
    %                  # Calculate I % N, stack = [(accumulator), I % N]
     +                 # Add the result of modulus to accumulator
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 5 bytes

```
s%LQS
```

---

```
s%LQS - Full program, inputs N from stdin and prints sum to stdout
s     - output the sum of
 %LQ  - the function (elem % N) mapped over 
    S - the inclusive range from 1..N
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/v1jVJzD4/39DEwA)

Comment: Oh actually I found a different 5 byter than you, didn't read yours correctly

Answer (score 2):

### Windows Batch (CMD), 63 bytes

```
@set s=0
@for /l %%i in (1,1,%1)do @set/as+=%1%%%%i
@echo %s%
```

Previous 64-byte version:

```
@set/ai=%2+1,s=%3+%1%%i
@if %i% neq %1 %0 %1 %i% %s%
@echo %s%
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 23 bytes

```ruby
->n{(1..n).sum{|i|n%i}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vWsNQTy9PU6@4NLe6JrMmTzWztvY/SMzQRFMvN7GguqaipkAhLboitvY/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## Julia 0.4, 15 bytes

```
x->sum(x%[1:x])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUz8n2b7v0LXrrg0V6NCNdrQqiJW839BUWZeSU6eRpqGoYmm5n8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 14 bytes

```
L,RAdx$p@BcB%s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99HJ8gxpUKlwMEp2Um1@P///4YmAA)

### How it works

```
L,   - Create a lambda function.
     - Example argument:     [7]
  R  - Range;        STACK = [[1 2 3 4 5 6 7]]
  A  - Argument;     STACK = [[1 2 3 4 5 6 7] 7]
  d  - Duplicate;    STACK = [[1 2 3 4 5 6 7] 7 7]
  x  - Repeat;       STACK = [[1 2 3 4 5 6 7] 7 [7 7 7 7 7 7 7]]
  $p - Swap and pop; STACK = [[1 2 3 4 5 6 7] [7 7 7 7 7 7 7]]
  @  - Reverse;      STACK = [[7 7 7 7 7 7 7] [1 2 3 4 5 6 7]]
  Bc - Zip;          STACK = [[7 1] [7 2] [7 3] [7 4] [7 5] [7 6] [7 7]]
  B% - Modulo each;  STACK = [0, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 0]
  s  - Sum;          STACK = [8]
```

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 61 bytes

*-2 bytes for removing the closing tag*

```php
<?php $z=fgets(STDIN);for($y=1;$y<$z;$y++){$x+=$z%$y;}echo$x;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxr4go0BBpco2LT21pFgjOMTF00/TOi2/SEOl0tbQWqXSRqUKSGpra1arVGjbqlSpqlRa16YmZ@SrVFj//29oAgA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) `-mx`, 3 bytes

```
N%U
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/30819P9/QxMF3dwKAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 9 bytes

```
⟨gz⟦₆⟩%ᵐ+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASUA2v9icmFjaHlsb2cy///in6hneuKfpuKChuKfqSXhtZAr//8xNP9a)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 23 bytes

```ruby
->n{eval [*0..n]*"+n%"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vOrUsMUchWstATy8vVktJO09Vqfa/hqGenqGJpl5uYkF1TUVNgUJadEVs7X8A)

Evaluates a string like `0+n%1+n%2+n%3+n%4+n%5` for n=5.

Answer (score 2):

## [Nim](https://nim-lang.org/), 52 bytes

```
import sugar,sequtils
n=>toSeq(1..n).foldl(a+n%%b,0)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m704LzN3wU31gqL8ZIVijTQrBRBLI88qM69EE0wo2CqkJmfkK6RpGJpoLi0tSdO1uGmemVuQX1SiUFyanlikU5xaWFqSmVPMVayRZ2tXkh-cWqhhqKeXp6mXlp-TkqORqJ2nqpqkY6AJ1b4ASkFpAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <s>13</s> 12 bytes

-1 byte from @ovs' improvement

```
+/1_!'/|1!:\
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#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)

- `|1!:\` generate a two-item list containing `(0..n; n)`
- `!'/` mod `n` by each of `0..n`
- `1_` drop the first result, corresponding to `n % 0`
- `+/` take the sum and (implicitly) return

Comment: Going tacit saves a byte: `f:+/1_!'/|1!:\ `

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 5 bytes

```
ΣṠM%ḣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9zihzsX@Ko@3LH4////hiYA)

#### Explanation

```
ΣṠM%ḣ  -- implicit input x, example: 5
 ṠM%   -- map (mod x) over the following..
    ḣ  -- ..the range [1..x]: [5%1,5%2,5%3,5%4,5%5] == [0,1,2,1,0]
Σ      -- sum: 0+1+2+1+0 == 4
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 23 + 1 (`-p`) = 24 bytes

```perl
//;map$\+=$'%$_,1..$_}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19f3zo3sUAlRttWRV1VJV7HUE9PJb62@v9/Q5N/@QUlmfl5xf91fU31DAwN/usWAAA)

Answer (score 1):

## Neim, 3 bytes

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##y0vNzP3//8PcCR0f5k5tAdJr/v83NAEA)

Explanation:

```
      # Inclusive range
     # Modulo each element with input
      # Sum the list
```

Answer (score 1):

## APL+WIN, 10 bytes

```
+/(⍳n)|n←⎕
```

Prompts for screen input.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 17 bytes

```
n->sum(m=1,n,n%m)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifpmCr8D9P1664NFcj19ZQJ08nTzVX839BUWZeiUaahqGJpuZ/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), <s>21</s> 16 bytes

<s>{sum $_ «%«(1..$_)}</s>

```
{sum $_ X%1..$_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/urg0V0ElXiFC1VBPTyW@9r@1QnFipUKahqGJpvV/AA)

-5 bytes (!) thanks to Brad Gilbert.

Comment: This challenge is getting way more submissions than I anticipated.

Comment: @StephenLeppik It's because it's easy... xD

Comment: `{sum $_ X%1..$_}`

Answer (score 1):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), <s>70</s> 62 bytes

```
(([{}])<>)({<<>(({})<<>{(({})){({}())<>}{}}>)<>>{}[({}())]}{})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X0Mjuro2VtPGTlOj2sbGTkOjulYTSFeDGZrVQFJDEyhbW11bawek7aproyFisUAhzf//DU0A)

It turns out that the straightforward approach is better.  Also, keeping a copy of n on the third stack instead of the first stack saves bytes.

```
(([{}])<>)                                                      Initialize both stacks with -n
           {                                              }{}   For all k from n down to 1:
             <>(({})<                      >)                   Store -n on third stack
                     <>{(({})){({}())<>}{}}                     Main part of standard modulus program
                                                                (except that the arguments are negative)
                                             <>
            <                                  >                Ignore evaluation of -n
                                                {}[({}())]      Recover n mod k, and decrement k for the next iteration
          (                                                  )  Sum over all iterations and push
```

Comment: Although we already had the [modulo challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/114321)... this one seems different. +1. Explanation?

Answer (score 1):

**Labyrinth - 45 Characters**

```
?:}}""):={%={{+
     ;        "
@!{{{-{=:}}}::}
```

Basically, it sets up by taking the input of the number that we are modulo summing. It then starts at one, takes the modulo of that number, and checks if it has reached the target number yet. If it hasn't, take the modulo again and add it to the previous one.

(I left out a lot of stack manipulations if you hadn't guessed, and yes, it actually does output the sum of the modulus up to that number)

Answer (score 1):

## [Clean](https://clean.cs.ru.nl), 39 bytes

Literally just [Bruce Forte's Haskell answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/150580/18730), but in Clean.

```
import StdEnv
@x=sum(map((rem)x)[1..x])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85JTcz7n5ufUpqTqpCbmJn3PzO3IL@oRCG4JMU1r4zLocK2uDRXIzexQEOjKDVXs0Iz2lBPryJW839wSSJQma2Cg4Khyf9/yWk5ienF/3U9ff67VOYl5mYmFwMA)

Comment: Well there's pretty much only one (short) way to solve this task.. Btw. using Haskell would save you 17 bytes ;P

Answer (score 1):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 35 bytes

```forth
: f 0 over 1 do over i mod + loop ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYtBCoAgFAX3nWJwG0pWq4Quk1lB8UWq65vS6s3AvCDp3vUW6uQ8EeiQd01YvPx0cImn5RSJuNJE/BPpMQmjQM@o8huqLwnX2JGYPw)

#### Explanation

Loops over all numbers from 1 to n-1 and adds n%i to the sum

#### Code Explanation

```forth
: f            \ start a new word definition
  0 over       \ add a 0 to the stack and place a copy of n above it
  1 do         \ start a counted loop from 1 to n-1
    over i     \ copy n to the the top of the stack and place the loop index above it
    mod +      \ take n%i and add it to the sum
  loop         \ end the counted loop
;              \ end the word definition
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Labyrinth](https://github.com/m-ender/labyrinth), 38 bytes

```
?_"):}}:{%={
@ ;        {
!{{=-{:}}:}+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P/fPl5J06q21qpa1baay0HBWgEKqrkUq6ttdatBcrXa//8bmgAA)

Slight improvement to [existing answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/150760/78410).

#### How it works

Stack notation is `a b ... c | d e ... f` where `a b ... c` part is the main stack, `d e ... f` is auxiliary, and `c` and `d` are the top of two stacks. I found this notation useful in developing and explaining the answer.

```
        Start at the top left
?_"     Push input and a 0, going straight through the junction
        n i=0 | sum=0
)       Increment i
:}}     n | i i sum
:{%=    n i | n%i sum
{{+}    n i | sum'=sum+n%i
:}}:{-  n n-i | i sum'
={      n i n-i | sum'
;       If n-i is nonzero, turn right and discard n-i, continuing the loop
{!@     Otherwise go straight, print sum and terminate
```

Comment: Starting from `n%n` and counting down to zero works better for [24 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P/fnsuKy6q21qqaS0NBQUGVq1a7utrWVtHh/39DEwA). I suspect the loop can still be golfed

Answer (score 1):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang), 30 bytes

```c
;=x+=s=y 0P;W>x=y+yT=s+s%x yOs
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVhbU9tGFH62f8XiDJbWlhtJuDMZy7KHpJBhSiCBpHkANzWyDJoRskeSG2igfz095@yutGubtGnLg8Tunuu35yZHveso@vosyaJ0NYuHRTlLFj/cjJr6TppcGVtReb@M14jyJLs2tsrkVtDM4nmSxSxNWbrIrulRbb4/@fCGefXy/P0Z8@vlL/tnrF8vD09esRf18uwD82riw@Nzjfbkw7FG@uHkzf75z3bBmQ2P9p/ej7w62z8HpeIoupnmHV4R6zRgp2Ifjfr1ycnBRzzK4Ah9eYD/hkPzHMXTOfzzYKcph5VB8PL09Jgo4DEGrwbgiqb77LU4BNbKuN@n6Srm/CKb8GaTzIYbiKe34Vnr4PTQ/hqEd92wCO@Z@zb4OLoL77v378OiW@zesfvT4isHolbQhCtZTvMitjn70mwkWcmSoNmAXRLvsM58lUWwgwpYBOvydukUy@zCn4RfXMd9DJrAxkJBD28XiD/fJGlsgzlAaAurHNa6LC@zy/llzr48XkxsPnjW4qS0kcyZLY1nYcisZxZnQoTa3YHdywy2u12xA0oacVrE@sajVMzspJgl10mp2EENWug5lZHi3WGey7qsI03sdjnrMcu1QBaalHCWx@Uqz0SIPjABORsOWZ9XXiZFuvgc53YEYpU@9vDAlA0RrSJy7JPFpbvJFleS0HMA3bDaXjMCMwGMgOhhQJLNVksbL4NJjHoMVlyyCX2XllUrb1kCbaACUyvt7PlzBvkK/4MJy2lRsvImBpnTvARiCWhHIYQ3EaGShrIK0/XvrIKnx8UNaV5jFLkTsCVSvhar5RKh5Or@1Y4OrB4pAKgmEGWooFtmEHFQLTDGpKkChvcWG1PdGMiNQ9zAyjHAioHhrKKEio3wzcY0QFOnabqI7L7reBw9wm3TCSH0TAP@rVWZQJIVm4dsMvm2Wb9/8PLVb@92jn861ZwwJPibEnYMEa@Pzp/i3dvkFea@tirLj56wvG/ymiSPWFPyVYawBVSYoGgsClvVFIpCiK8yiRidXq3mF35/Io0Q4Lcp5yrtxRJ6Szm3gRS82k3TWUsl82gE2eigkHUBEJmVAFHhhX6Dbsi8PdNJ9BzjY8xaZb6KWxAX1T6GCezPp5CveNDKVmnaqiFAP9F1WZsRjE8vF4sUDq5MAJ50tfbqW/50vt8h3cqrdSvxzspF9r/aCJFYLtLU1k11mOtA1f0XJmcbJmOzerP/9sTBliXiDJZHF57ruhPqbLBUqyL5I/5UMnwFzTpCNW8RAVg5@PDpuRd6qvNh0cHmhy96@uK1BwSHR8cHHTaHehU0qsiW@rAURtOlk8YZNUoNK1t2FYEZ5NxTYKwzYiPAPjJf5FAzqeVCfxsSFgEU9gQPq2IQ3S7XboBASiZ1XUCYkgmqKT4nZXRjd2jOYOagARgx@Rdhr7D2rQFDLYIgREBxUIHCyNvklBQv5yMjZHlALa@moAGszLF90Ax2MeFf6jCDOYPKrVB8BopN2fk0m9m87d7N4a8mfAuEIFRAdB2XKQxTdpuuso0XhF1qlmQ8SOa2TdeJzTe6ydEUB8KUc3HLoRtsNRVeaJfSdyD0UXeiWiDxCJS5iJGsm7WVL2t3BH118qo@QU4d4YrmN6DBYIDwC5eLZZzZmmKnlbeoW4NV4a3oXRCOoe/2X9C@7O@2GArmYPoMnYKpCCLWwZEJyKF90wp1gGoVXTZssm5IYwcmLFByCTfIIV0ENUrohMzXx4YaxtqTd@BJfAcjEyb7hp87xqXTvLyDhWyD8HgjOkBLauKikf9kDeRMtiWOq8In@0/rZHV7BfMIdiCuWhB@DNRD3EY1VKzn9H1k7xbIaObCJjPACcOIrhcKKW/VpOoAu0s8zaTYpxqY7Fj6DaiGLlA4rVHAxIArlKCJ@zSgY@02nl70ekg6EZPmJY22DWXW7g@dAuyxYcWZSrVcM39VFur2q5gQ05cwqFsZRGUSyiVWZAwt7XrEQNswb1t8qCE1zNhMxZIv7hxHUEoGcQFEhduY5aHy0ufbQzWaluol50CvW8PE1f8oi8N86NC7lDVC@tXbiE4t2nFaNu0VTJ36dragsN6dt@DQ2cBB3Os2FG63uNYhmlAXQgzQgmyqkKF1Cd9NSBT0eiRPAkUdc/2iBaKlkf3PvwnM8@3A7H6TaXc706@EpuGQGOZpz9e9DCTsAvWQ9bwKZaIF6D3Is54HOebpxP53Ug@hPBq0YYikpHegdlwFOQHtj1yJtc9pWumEhH9zPSHoUOtSQ/J/rZZiHhmpFpqJNmZ6PA11ZJF1IH7bAGZBMGbG6EGbDtMSDGW4glNVcV@UFqTdCaGAaSaP/rvJo//B5JEyeWeLzaG0WZo8ftpkoXWLyXg8ZgaBX1H4qvbubLOzXlTuqaDVBVTmtevMQV@2lZWxzimjsOJ/@Cf8Mnw1MRV/YA10amNCWqcN64Q1j797BFZjUT0DI13DmIOrLCIalDgJDW4tw5ADKbrdik2Y/BHcEz9h6DOK4R3T255kOzIHPiTV@Mf@YE@D5bWYNkOtOXf12rU5XWdyZnWqXNgzZqFzAfSa0GC9WvrbquUer1qIX3H3afNveikahm@8iqiaG6tOqrdVHzxErV0P@yv1FhH/4pBeRNGVmQDaZ/F8ukpL8EwNJ0kGh8mMfn2YRmWcQyOJLBxXcIezJ75/UBjNp/K3rEf6Ar2dJpnN8ScN@gjBn7xtlxSbw/7jV6//Fw)

Pretty straightforward.

```php
# init x with input converted to number,
# and sum and y to 0
; = x + (= sum = y 0) PROMPT
# for 1..x
; WHILE (> x (= y + y 1))
    # sum += x % y
    : = sum + s (% x y)
: OUTPUT sum
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), <s>37</s> 30 bytes

```powershell
param($a)1..$a|%{$r+=$a%$_}
$r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNydFNzi9K/f@/ILEoMVdDJVHTUE9PJbFGtVqlSNtWJVFVJb6WS6Xo////hiYA)

*-7 bytes thanks to [@mazzy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80745/mazzy)!*

Comment: sum is shorter [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNydFNzi9K/f@/ILEoMVdDJVHTUE9PJbFGtVqlSNtWJVFVJb6WS6Xo////hiYA "PowerShell Core – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 24 bytes

Equivalent to [my Ruby answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/150569/11261).

```
(:-&(:& &:%|:+&:sum))%:+
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700K740qXLBojTbpaUlaboWOzSsdNU0rNQU1KxUa6y01ayKS3M1NVWttCHSywsU0qINTWIhvAULIDQA)

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 16 bytes (Non-competitive)

```
{+/{x!g}'1+!g-1}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs6rW1q+uUEyvVTfUVkzXNazl4kq3MjThSouOVdBXMDYE8owMoDwzEM8YxjM0tgAA73sOtQ==)

Non-competitive, because required the use of a global variable called `g` to get input. The reason is because lambda functions in K cannot access variables  of another function if they are in that function.

Explanation:

```
{+/{x!g}'1+!g-1}    Main function. Takes g as input (g=14)
           !        Generate a range from 0 to
            g-1     g - 1 (exclusive)               (g-1=13=>range=0..12)
         1+         + 1 for each element            (range=1..13)
        '           For each element
   {   }            Execute a function that returns
    x!g             g mod x (x = element)
 +/                 Sum
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 52 bytes

```go
func(n int)(o int){for k:=1;k<=n;k++{o+=n%k};return}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY1NCoMwFIT3OcUjICTElv4tSmM2PUEP0E2wpjyCLxJiN-JJupFCD-VtqtbF8MHAN_P-PMMw8saW3j4rqC0Sw7oJMcGWuzpx9rIRHJhvm9zmPJ5cS6UgQEpShAWdCxH8xey1Lwxpr1QXlKHM9zpWqY3Ur-51dpcLIaFjs4azhoU57DQqNZW3OE06wbPjA6bcieeYgxMoJevZujQMf_4A)

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 20 bytes

```
Sum[Mod[#,i],{i,#}]&
```

[View it on Wolfram Cloud!](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/2d8e8611-e52e-4dc7-a490-2fe0d8c580fa)

Comment: `Mod[#,]~Sum~{,#}&`

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `S`, 2 bytes

```
R%
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0UrBS7IKlpSVpuhaLglSXFCclF0O5CxYZmkBYAA)

##### Explanation

```python
R%  # Implicit input.
R   # Range. Push [1..input].
 %  # Mod. Vectorises.
    # S flag sums.
    # Implicit output.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Rockstar](https://codewithrockstar.com/), 91 bytes

```
listen to N
D's 0
O's 0
while N-D
let D be+1
let M be N/D
turn M down
let O be+N-M*D

say O
```

[Try it](https://codewithrockstar.com/online) (Code will need to be pasted in)

Answer (score 1):

## [Trilangle](https://github.com/bbrk24/Trilangle), 45 bytes

```
<'?0'1...Lj2'<.zj2'.......L-)S+%,7#..@!,,,/^S
```

Try it on [the online interpreter](https://bbrk24.github.io/Trilangle/#%3C%27%3F0%271...Lj2%27%3C.zj2%27.......L-)S%2B%25%2C7%23..%40!%2C%2C%2C%2F%5ES)!

TODO: add colorized explanation

```
<'?0'1...Lj2'<.zj2'.......L-)S+%,7#..@!,,,/^S

  ?                                           Get number from stdin
   0'                                         Start sum at 0
 '   1                                        Start counter at 1
          j2'  zj2'       L-     7            Compare the counter and the input
                                     @!,,,/   If they're the same, print the sum and exit
                            )S+%,           S Otherwise, add one iteration and increment the counter
             <      .             #        ^  Loop
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 7 [bytes](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=U0JDUyDihpAgK0BcMOKKlwpEZWNvZGUg4oaQIOKHjOKKjy0x4pa9wrEu4o2Y4ouv4oav4oqCwq8x4qe74ouv4qe7LOKHjOKItSjihpjCrzHii68rMjU2KSAtQFwwKzEKJnAg4oqCIjggYml0IGVuY29kaW5nOlx0IiBTQkNTICLih4ziio8tMeKWvcKxLuKNmOKLr-KGr-KKgsKvMeKnu-KLr-Knuyzih4ziiLUo4oaYwq8x4ouvKzI1NikiIOKKgitAXDDih6ExMjkiLiziiLY74oiYwqzCscKv4oy14oia4peL4oyK4oyI4oGFPeKJoDziiaQ-4omlKy3Dl8O34pe_4oG_4oKZ4oan4oal4oig4qe74paz4oeh4oqi4oeM4pmt4ouv4o2J4o2P4o2W4oqa4oqb4oqd4pah4oqU4omF4oqf4oqC4oqP4oqh4oav4oaZ4oaY4oa74per4pa94oyV4oiK4oqXL-KIp1xc4oi14omh4oi64oqe4oqg4o2l4oqV4oqc4oip4oqT4oqD4oqZ4ouF4o2Y4o2c4o2a4qyaJz_ijaPijaQh4o6L4oas4pqCzrfPgM-E4oiefl9bXXt9KCnCr0AkXCLihpB8IyIKJnAg4oqCImRlY29kZWQ6XHQiIERlY29kZSAiwqPCsS0xwrjChy7DjMKlwrPCsMKIMcKfwqXCnyzCo8K_KMK1wogxwqUrMjU2KSIg4oqCK0BcMOKHoTEyOSIuLOKItjviiJjCrMKxwq_ijLXiiJril4vijIrijIjigYU94omgPOKJpD7iiaUrLcOXw7fil7_igb_igpnihqfihqXiiKDip7vilrPih6HiiqLih4zima3ii6_ijYnijY_ijZbiipriipviip3ilqHiipTiiYXiip_iioLiio_iiqHihq_ihpnihpjihrvil6vilr3ijJXiiIriipcv4oinXFziiLXiiaHiiLriip7iiqDijaXiipXiipziiKniipPiioPiipnii4XijZjijZzijZrirJonP-KNo-KNpCHijovihqzimoLOt8-Az4TiiJ5-X1tde30oKcKvQCRcIuKGkHwjIg==)

```
/+◿+1⇡.
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=ZiDihpAgLyvil78rMeKHoS4KCuKItWbih6ExNA==)

```
/+◿+1⇡.
      .  # duplicate
     ⇡   # range
   +1    # plus one
  ◿      # mod
/+       # sum
```

Answer (score 1):

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), 8 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```
+/⊢|⍨1↓⍳
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=09Z/1LWo5lHvCsNHbZMf9W4GAA&f=e9Q39VHbhDQFQxMA&i=AwA&r=tryapl&l=apl-dyalog&m=train&n=f)

Answer (score 0):

## C, 43 bytes

```
s,m;f(n){for(s=m=0;m++<n;s+=n%m);return s;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYsxCsMwDAB3v0IEDBJ2IelUqvgnXYpTFw1Wi51OIW93ndx4x8XLO8bWqs@cUGlLn4I15DBydm5Wri6ozcTltf6KQuW9ia6Qn6JIZjPQ6Q/gYSVMDDKH6XpjcE7ozAff0nvCwS53sMtDBw/iIaEQsdnbHw)

## C (gcc), 38 bytes

```
s,m;f(n){for(s=m=0;m++<n;s+=n%m);s=s;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYoxCsMwDAB3v0IEDBJ2IelUqugnXYqDgwarJe4W8nbH6Y13l25rSq3VWDij0Z4/G1YpMnIJYTauQcwX4iqVj6b2g/JWQ3K7g07fAS@rMjHoLNP9wRCC0j9ffLfeMw5@eYJfXjZE0AgZlYjd0U4)

Comment: That's my best, too: `a;i;f(n){a=0;for(i=n;--i;)a+=n%i;return a;}`

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 9 bytes

```
-~1#.i.|]
```

### How it works

```
        ] - the argument 
       |  - mod   
     i.   - list from 0 to argument - 1
  1#.     - sum (base 1 conversion)
-~        - subtract the argument (to get rid of the n mod 0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qfbmulYKAAxP916wyV9TL1amL/a3Ip6SmopynY6qkr6CjUWimkc6UmZ@QrpCkYmsBYJob/AQ)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 7 bytes

```
$+a%\,a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P9fRTtRNUYn8f///4YmAA)

```
         a is 1st cmdline arg
    \,a  Inclusive range from 1 through a
  a%     Take a mod each of those numbers (a%a is 0, so doesn't affect the sum)
$+       Fold on +
         Output (implicit)
```

Answer (score 0):

## MATLAB, 19 bytes

```
@(n)sum(mod(n,1:n))
```

Very straightforward, `mod` calculates `n%x` for each natural number below `n`. and `sum` just sums them all. Test:

```
@(n)sum(mod(n,1:n))
ans(14)
ans = 

    @(n)sum(mod(n,1:n))
ans =
    31.0000e+000
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 8 bytes

```
@:…)¦%¦Σ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz/38HqUcMyzUPLVA8tO7f4/39DEwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), <s>69</s> 68 bytes

```
	N =INPUT
A	I =I + 1
	S =LT(I,N) S + REMDR(N,I)	:S(A)
	OUTPUT =S
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/n9NPwdbTLyA0hMuR0xPIVNBWMOTiDFaw9QnR8NTx01QIBooEufq6BGn46XhqcloFazhqcnH6h4YA9SjYBnO5@rn8/28GAA)

```
	N =INPUT				;* read in input
A	I =I + 1				;* I is initialized to 0 so this increments it to 1
	S =LT(I,N) S + REMDR(N,I)	 :S(A)	;* similarly with S, add to the remainder
	LT(I,N) :S(A)				;* on success (I < N), goto A
	OUTPUT =S				;* output the sum
END						;* terminate the program
```

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 38 bytes

```
#(apply +(for[i(range 1 %)](mod % i)))
```

Well this is boring, I was hoping `#(apply +(map mod(repeat %)(range 1 %)))` would have been shorter as `mod` gets rarely used in `map` context.

Answer (score 0):

## J, 14 Bytes

```
M=:+/@:|~}.@i.
```

#### How it works:

```
M=:                 | Define the verb M
            i.      | Get integers in the range [0, input)
         }.@        | Remove the leading 0
       |~           | Take the original input mod each of these integers, making a new array
   +/@:             | Sum this array
```

#### Example:

```
    M 14
31
    M"0 >:i.20    NB. Apply M to each of the integers from 1-20 inclusive
0 0 1 1 4 3 8 8 12 13 22 17 28 31 36 36 51 47 64 61
```

Answer (score 0):

## Common Lisp, <s>50</s> 47 bytes

```
(lambda(n)(loop as i from 1 to n sum(mod n i)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcZLCsAgDAXAq7xlshR6oVQpBPIRbc@fuhmmm@5ZNJdGBxWZ@D2EgskyJ2RD8ax0NLyJwP6cPMeZMnO16/AD)

Answer (score 0):

## Befunge-93, 36 bytes

```
p&:10p1>-#1:_$v_g.@
 :p00+g00%\g01<^
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/v0DNytCgwNBOV9nQKl6lLD5dz4FLwarAwEA73cBANSbdwNAm7v9/QxMA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), 13 bytes

```
&1{:2d%vh;OS#
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kygtzqj8/1/NsNrKKEW1LMPaP1j5////hiYA)**

```
&1{                 \ Make the stack [n, 1, n]
   :     ;          \ n times do (this consumes last n):
    2d              \    Copy the last two items
      %v            \    Get remainder and put result on stack
        h           \    Increment divisor
          OS        \ Sum the second stack
            #       \ Output the result
```

Answer (score 0):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 31 bytes

```
[dz%rdz<B]sBd1<B0*0[+z1<C]dsCxp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcuxDsIgFIXh3ae4iXHRBUpba8JS@gIM3QgTVw0JNo23Q@Xl0UtcvuX8B0ORbXGYT2/M2ngyKLURZ@EuWerJI037WkY72uBw6QarGvsv0m8JnmYAOALF15ri4wPbnba4PA8yzTs0jGJapmN65soMzI2RotZVVe35Wr4)

Assume our input is the only value on the stack. Macro `B` duplicates top of stack, calculates stack depth, and performs modulo. Runs until stack depth is equal to the input. This works for numbers greater than 1, so we don't run `B` automatically, but instead only if it's greater than 1 (`d1<B`). `B` leaves the input value on top-of-stack, so we multiply by 0. Since 0 is the desired result for an input of 1, this is fine for 1 as well. However, 1 doesn't leave us enough items on the stack to do the initial summation in macro `C`, so we put another 0 on the stack just in case. Macro `C` simply adds the two values on top of the stack, and keeps going until the stack only has a single value. Finally, we `p`rint.

Answer (score 0):

### F#, 35 bytes

```
let s v=Seq.sumBy(fun x->v%x){1..v}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyvWTc4vSv3/Pye1RKFYocw2OLVQr7g016lSI600T6FC165MtUKz2lBPr6z2f7SNa15JUWVAfmZeiV0sF0hLbmJmnkJiUXqZgi2XAhAUKxiagBk1dgoFRUB1aXkKSqqZSmAxg/8A)

Pretty straight-forward.

Answer (score 0):

## [Ahead](https://github.com/ajc2/ahead), 21 bytes

```
I&l@O+K<
~>td-! ntd%~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8xITUz5/99TLcfBX9vbhqvOriRFV1EhryRFte7/f0MTAA)

Answer (score 0):

## MMIX, 32 bytes (8 instrs)

```
00000000: c1020000 e3010000 1cff0002 25020201  Ḋ£¡¡ẉ¢¡¡÷”¡£%££¢
00000010: feff0006 200101ff 5b02fffc f8020000  “”¡© ¢¢”[£”‘ẏ£¡¡
```

```
modsum  SET  $2,$0              // i = n
        SET  $1,0               // s = 0
0H      DIV  $255,$0,$2
        SUB  $2,$2,1
        GET  $255,rR
        ADD  $1,$1,$255         // loop: s += n % i--
        PBNZ $2,0B              // if(i) goto loop
        POP  2,0                // return [s,n]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), <s>15</s> 13 bytes

```
ns,[:lf%f,]&+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/z@vWCfaKidNNU0nVk37/39DEwA)

*Thanks LyricLy for the tip that dropped 2 chars.*

This generates the modulo numbers on a stack, then sums them and relies on the default action to print the stack to show the answer.

```
ns,             # Read the N req from STDIN, stash it away, then decrement
    [     ,]    # Loop to decrement the top of stack and exit then that's 0
     :l         # Duplicate the top of stack, restore N from backup cell
       f%f      # Flip top two stack enrtries, do modulo math, flip again
             &+ # Sum the stack
                # Ends with one entry on the stack, which prints as a number
```

Comment: `,` is a shorthand for `1-` that saves 2 bytes here.

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.unicode`, 33 bytes

```
[ dup [1,b) [ mod ] with map Σ ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQnVqUl5qjkJtYkqFXlJiXnloMZisUpxaWpuYlQ7l6pXmZyfkpqQoFRaklJZUFRZl5JQrWXFyGJv@jFVJKCxSiDXWSNBWiFXLzUxRiFcozgSbkJhYonFusEPs/OTEnR0HvPwA)

- `dup` Duplicate the input.

  **Stack:** (e.g.) `14 14`
- `[1,b)` Make a range from `1` inclusive to `14` exclusive.

  **Stack:** `14 { 1 2 ... 13 }`
- `[ mod ] with map` Do `14 1 mod`, `14 2 mod`, `14 3 mod`, etc. and collect the results in a sequence the same length as the range.

  **Stack:** `{ 0 0 2 2 4 2 0 6 5 4 3 2 1 }`
- `Σ` Sum.

  **Stack:** `31`

Answer (score 0):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 21 bytes

```arturo
$->n[∑map n'x->n%x]
```

[Try it!](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?D0JmQn)

Answer (score 0):

### Malbolge Unshackled, 1,828,225 bytes.

Available [on GitHub](https://github.com/kspalaiologos/codegolf-submissions/blob/master/150563.mb) as StackExchange does not allow posting answers this long.

Use as, having obtained fast20 or any Malbolge Unshackled interpreter:

```
$ echo -ne "\xFF" | time ./fast20 150563.mb | xxd
00000000: c3
```