# Divmod continuously until the remainder is 1 or 0, then get the remainder

Tags: code-golf, math, number, integer, division

The task is simple, divide, get the quotient and the remainder, and if the remainder isn't 1 or 0, do the same thing (quotient divmod remainder) until the remainder is 1 or 0, then get the remainder. If the last input number is 1 or 0, output it.

If the input is `[15, 4]`, then the output would be `0`, because the divmod of `15` and `4` is `[3, 3]` which if you do it again, you get `[1, 0]`, and you can't divmod further, then get the last element, and you got `0`.

Another example would be `[102, 7]`, which if you divmod, you get `[14, 4]`, which if you do again, you get `[3, 2]`, which if you divmod again, you get `[1, 1]`, and you get the last element `1`, which is the output.

Both input numbers are assumed to be non-negative integers less than 1000.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program/function in bytes wins.

### Testcases:

```
[15, 4] => 0
[102, 7] => 1
[20, 2] => 0
[10, 0] => 0
[11, 1] => 1
[99, 7] => 1
[45, 45] => 0
[31, 30] => 1
[999, 7] => 0
[999, 6] => 1
[88, 7] => 0
[1, 999] => 1
[98, 7] => 0
[999, 998] => 1
```

Comment: Is it permissible to output two unique outputs for 1 and 0 other than 1 and 0?

Comment: It would also be worth clarifying the spec. As currently written, I would say that `[10, 0]` is an invalid input because the spec suggests there is always at least one divmod. You’ve also not specified that the input have to be integers or non-negative, but the examples would suggest that is the case.

Comment: "and if the remainder is 1 or 0, do the same thing" - is that supposed to say "if the remainder *isn't* 1 or 0"?

Comment: @user2357112 Fixed

Comment: So this is the gcd algorithm, but implemented by a student who sucks at arithmetic!

Comment: @NickKennedy Yes, you can also output True and False or any other output format, but must be unique.

Answer (score 5):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 4 bytes

```
ʷ{Ƶþ
```

```
ʷ{Ƶþ
ʷ{      While; run the following code until it fails
  Ƶ       Check if the absolute value of the top of the stack is greater than 1
   þ      Divmod
```

Both `Ƶ` and `þ` are new built-ins in [Nekomata 0.5.1](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata/releases/tag/v0.5.1.0), which is not yet on ATO.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 27 bytes

```javascript
f=(p,q)=>q>1?f(p/q|0,p%q):q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hc9NDoIwEAXgvaeYjUmbVDvDj7Ym4FkIgtEQ2opx5d0rVTcYiusv772Za/Wohvp2sfdNb06N923BrHC8KF1Jx5ZZ6Z4o7Nrxg/O16QfTNdvOnFnLgHIBABnnICXgaqqESdD9R@lHIcGgyXwW6K0YUwpKkWatl3azcHOWR5rT0JzifFZPmnFed5FdpRay4zNivFvHPlL/drVW36x/AQ)

Or **[25 bytes](https://tio.run/##jY/LDoIwEEX3fsVsTNqkSqegUhPwWwhSoyF9iPH3K1Q2kgxxM5sz99yZR/NuhvZ596@dddcuRlMxLwKv6lDjxTCfBeG3gZ9DbJ0dXN/te3djhgEerACAwnIOWQZy88tRqsRPM8cFByUTV0Qe8MslyTFxpPxar/cX6f5xEv48@XNJ5PXCLwl@pPrLcjU/fSZgslD/lX/063FrzscP)** with BigInts.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 35 bytes

```python
f=lambda a,b:f(a/b,a%b)if b>1else b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY/RasMgFIbvfYpDYESH6zRttyRgXyQtQ1nchNRIYqF7@kyXasvO3c//fedw3I//Hm21LFoM8qw@JUiqWo3lq6LySRGjQR14P8w9qMWDgKIoOr6nsDuBOABDHWcVhfe/xFFXMQrVvaLAcuAUeMKa5sHZxXX7xG0Dt2V3MJPslt5SV9cPVbBCm7X6v9U09VqGBxDS4wSDsT0YC34zu8F4XB5tSVoEYeT0NX/4/uopjBfvLvHxiCcyLipJRkN7lg4bG/isdrx94adk0MCvgpsChzV@jiQBISDm9Qwhyy8)

Comment: -1: `f=lambda a,b:1-(b>1>f(a/b,a%b))**b`

Comment: @Albert.Lang Uh. I learned something today.

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 33 bytes

```r
f=\(x,y)`if`(y>1,f(x%/%y,x%%y),y)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGCpaUlaboWNxXTbGM0KnQqNRMy0xI0Ku0MddI0KlT1VSt1KlRVKzWBEhCFG9I0DA2MdMw1uYAMUx0TqDDMHAA)

A recursive function taking two arguments and returning 1 or 0.

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 27 bytes

```c
f(a,b){a=b>1?f(a/b,a%b):b;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7JjsJADETv/ooSKCgtNUw6bGkyCR8yM4deWFqCBrGIA8q3BzcafLBcz1WW3XjnXN9vcyOteJrGtmrN4stKk1mxsnXXD0N0h7vf4Pt68@E02bdEId5wNCHmAk8CVwJGwtb0lo99OGyQX52J23yQeWT@Nw4kRuwZWYGmQfmJpjpf@AA7fzIv2fuHpv1E0lWJ9CCsEPU70lHXqzlmpIoSSyoLlDyiIKWgSGtmM17PaaowLRgkkvqCqopHBRakq3@qdUUv)

Answer (score 3):

## x86-32 machine code, 9 bytes

### x86-64 machine code, 10 bytes, same asm source

Args in EAX (dividend), ECX (divisor), return value in ECX (0 or 1 final remainder).

To call from C, `gcc -mregparm=3` will put args in EAX, EDX, ECX in that order (so a dummy second arg works), but won't look for retval in ECX.  Returning in EAX costs 1 extra byte for `xchg eax,ecx` at the end.

Args must be signed non-negative.  (At least the dividend must be; the divisor can be full-range 32-bit unsigned.  And the first remainder must also be non-negative).  Divisor must be non-zero or the first iteration will fault.

```
               divmod_repeat:
               .loop:
 99               cdq        ; zero-extend (for numbers that fit as non-negative integers)
 F7F1             div ecx        ; EAX = EDX:EAX/ecx unsigned; EDX = remainder
                
 89D1             mov ecx, edx
 4A               dec edx        ; 1 byte instruction in 32-bit mode
 7FF8             jg .loop       ; }while(remainder-- > 1);   or  }while(--rem > 0)
 C3               ret            

               ;   cmp ecx, 2     ; simple but less golfed version
               ;   jae .loop      ; }while(new_divisor >= 2);
```

This shows a hexdump of the 32-bit machine code on the left, from a NASM listing.  The x86-64 version (still using 32-bit operand-size) uses `FFCA dec edx`.

Not much scope for golfing, other than choosing a good calling convention.  `div` only works with EDX:EAX / src, producing its outputs in EDX (remainder) and EAX (quotient).  We don't want to touch quotient, so all the special-case accumulator short-form encodings of instructions like `xchg eax, reg` and `cmp al, imm8`.

But we can destroy the old copy of the remainder in EDX after copying it to ECX as the new divisor (or return value).  So we can use 1-byte (in 32-bit mode) `dec reg` to set FLAGS instead of `cmp`.  The next iteration's `cdq` will overwrite EDX anyway, and we need `cdq` anyway.

We can only use signed conditions with `dec` because it leaves CF unmodified, but is otherwise like `sub` or `cmp ecx, 1`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org) <sup>[SBCS](https://tinyurl.com/Uiua-SBCS-Jan-14)</sup>, 13 bytes

```
⊙◌⍢(:⌊⊃÷◿|>1)
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_8_0__ZiDihpAg4oqZ4peM4o2iKDrijIriioPDt-KXv3w-MSkKCmYgNCAxNQpmIDcgMTAyCmYgMiAyMApmIDAgMTAKZiAxIDExCmYgNyA5OQpmIDQ1IDQ1CmYgMzAgMzEKZiA3IDk5OQpmIDYgOTk5CmYgNyA4OApmIDk5OSAxCmYgNyA5OApmIDk5OCA5OTkK)

```
⊙◌⍢(:⌊⊃÷◿|>1)
  ⍢(     |  )  # while
          >1   # top of stack is greater than one
      ⊃÷◿      # quotient and remainder
     ⌊         # take the floor of the quotient
    :          # swap so remainder is on top
⊙◌             # drop the quotient from the stack
```

Comment: That version of the SBCS does not have the `◌` glyph added today. Here's my updated version: http://tinyurl.com/Uiua-SBCS-Jan-14

Comment: @Tbw Thanks, updated.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 35 bytes

```
.+
$*
+`(..+)¶(\1)*(.*)
$3¶$#2$*
^.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYxNCsIwEEb3OcWAEfLHkElbTRZ6kVSpoAs3LsSz9QC9WIzVpMXV8PHem@ftdX9c0lYMKPqrlgbmg4pxN42cEmrGFdODQNRyGkVPUglUkvEm843L8IwpReoMtCc4HMGySNYZ2M@LWHTWgFuQAVsHGaCihbBq2s@7rnhN9hq7iNW0v7UrzPsVylWmNfP/VQj@C98) Takes the integers in reverse order on separate lines but link is to test suite that takes input in the format given in the question. Explanation:

```
.+
$*
```

Convert to unary.

```
(..+)¶(\1)*(.*)
$3¶$#2$*
```

If the denominator is at least `2`, divmod the numerator by the denominator, replacing the denominator by the remainder and the numerator by the quotient.

```
+`
```

Repeat until the denominator is reduced to less than `2`.

```
^.
```

Convert the denominator to `0` or `1`.

Answer (score 2):

## Scratch, <s>77</s> 70 bytes

Ports @enzo's answer. Run without screen refresh.

```
define(x)(y
if<(y)>(1)>then
([floor v]of((x)/(y)))((x)mod(y
else
say(y
```

[image]

Comment: `set[i v]to(y` => `say(y`, with "run without screen refresh" checked on

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
[`D!#‰
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/OsFFUflRwwYgy9DASMc8FgA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/6AQXReVHDRv@1@r8j442NNUxidWJNjQw0jEH0kYGOkZgro4BiDLUMQRSlpZgOROgUlMgbWyoY2wAFoaIg2gzIG1hAeYa6gAFQMIWcFlLSwuwBMgwkMmxAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
[       # Start an infinite loop:
 `      #  Pop and push both values in the pair separately to the stack
        #  (which will use the implicit input-pair in the first iteration)
  D     #  Duplicate the top value (the remainder)
   !    #  Take its factorial (0 becomes 1; 1 remains 1; ≥2 becomes larger)
    #   #  If it's truthy (==1), stop the infinite loop
        #  (after which the duplicated remainder is output implicitly as result)
     ‰  #  (else) Divmod the two values
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Funge-98](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Funge-98), 51 bytes

```
v   >.@   @.<
>    "HTRF"4 (&& v
\/RRw1`1:%OOw1`1:<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tNAtqAQz//8vU1BQsNNzAJIOejZcdkBaQckjJMhNyURBQ01NoYwrRj8oqNwwwdBK1d8fTNv8/29oymXCBQA)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, nice first answer!

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 47 bytes

```go
func(a,b int)int{for b>1{a,b=a/b,a%b}
return b}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XVHNSsQwEMZrnmIsFloYu-3-aFfIgqBXEe1NRZJusxTdbMmmooQ-hicvi-BDrU9j0tZd9JDJzHzfN5mZfHwuVpvtUcXyJ7YoYMlKSUi5rFZKR55Yao-QF6ZAAIWvWovjdDsQtcwDhhxKqUN7jFgp4LPE2BxlA47M5w1Rha6VBN50su-Dd_1WFZDBWqs61-DYWLxWrkpDiCvavh6EYIgu1noNZxTuHjJDTDJBGCPEDVo_HiKcIiQuGMYIwx1gnV8_sYSeM53u-WNXaNKTRpYxinesjhbvgpMeSdM9YBUt1knSf4qpyzjIznOt7FzPMvAopXCbnd9kYD0vJG5Zj6jdcIpJu_JuVkNY3iZFoCOGOuIhKQW45CEFHblNGWirisDz5wj-HOjM2cCfh_fSQ3BCazg6GXaiEBrbzp9u4PLqAvpu-t_ZbLr7Bw)

Answer (score 1):

### Google Sheets, 74 bytes

```cpp
=LET(F,LAMBDA(F,d,m,LET(x,MOD(d,m),IF(x<2,x,F(F,INT(d/m),x)))),F(F,A1,A2))
```

Simple recursive function that stops the execution when the remainder is 0 or 1.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 10 bytes

```
eu?>eG1.DF
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72koLIkY8ESt0C9wKWlJWm6FqtSS-3tUt0N9VzcIAILINSyaCXdFKXYm9XRsVzRhqY6CiYg2sBIR8EcyDAy0FEwAgvoKBiAaEMdBUMgbWkJkTcBaTAFMoyBEsYGYBmoFJhhBmRYWEAEgCqAYiAZCyQVlpYWsRCXAAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
d/ỊṪ¬Ɗ¿Ṫ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z9F/@Huroc7Vx1ac6zr0H4g4//DnfusHzXMUdC1U3jUMNf6cDtQQIXr6OSHOxeDhG3tgKIPdyw6OinscDvXw91bDrc/aloT@f9/tKGpjoJJLFCBggFXtKGBkY6COZhnyBVtZKCjYISQ0lEwgHMMdRQMYcosLZH0mICMM4WpMwaqMzZAKISrNIDyzGByFhZIUkBdQFm4Ngt0XZaWFhBJAA)

A monadic link taking a pair of non-negative integers and returning 1 or 0.

### Explanation

```
     Ɗ¿  | While the following is true:
  Ị      | - <= 1
   Ṫ     | - Tail (i.e. second list member)
    ¬    | - Not
d/       | … Reduce using divmod
       Ṫ | Tail
```

If we were allowed to guarantee the second input were non-zero, this is shorter:

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
d/%/¿ṪỊ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z9FX1X/0P6HO1c93N31/@HOfdaPGuYo6NopPGqYa324HSigwnV08sOdi0HCtnZA0Yc7Fh2dFHa4nevh7i2H2x81rYn8/z/a0FRHwSQWqEDBgCva0MBIR8EczDPkijYy0FEwgksZ6igYwmQsLZGUmYBMMIWpMwaqMzZAKISrNIDyzGByFhZIUkBdQFm4Ngt0XZaWFhBJAA)

Comment: Can you please explain it? I like this language.

Comment: @Fmbalbuena thanks, hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

## TI-BASIC, 37 bytes

```
While 1<Ans(2
Ans→L
Ans(1)/Ans(2
int({Ans,ʟL(2)fPart(Ans
End
Ans(2
```

Takes input in `Ans`. Replace the second to fourth lines with `int({Ans(1)/Ans(2),remainder(Ans(1),Ans(2` for -2 bytes if `remainder(` is supported.

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 23 bytes

```
ＮθＮηＷ∧⊖ηη«≔﹪θιη≔÷θιθ»Ｉη
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc29CsIwFIbh2VxFxhOos4VMxS4dLN5CTA4mkJ7Y/NRBvPYYBcXx5YHv01ZFHZSvdaJbyXNZLhhhFZL9t219t84jh4EMjKgjLkgZTaOOWyH4g@2GlNyV4BRM8QHWjruPyZ9MlEe3OYNffP882Tk6ynBUKbc1IWvte3ao@82/AA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Lack of divmod and recursion makes this annoyingly long.

```
ＮθＮη
```

Input the two values.

```
Ｗ∧⊖ηη«
```

Compare the second value against both `1` and `0`, but in such a way that if it is neither than the implicit loop variable has the same value.

```
≔﹪θιη≔÷θιθ
```

Modulo and divide the first value by the copy of the second, thus allowing the second and first values to be safely overwritten.

```
»Ｉη
```

Output the final value.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-Minteger -ap`, 37 bytes

```perl
@F=("@F"/$_,"@F"%$_)while($_=$F[1])>1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/9/BzVZDycFNSV8lXgdEq6rEa5ZnZOakaqjE26q4RRvGatoZ/v9vaGCko2D@L7@gJDM/r/i/rq@pnoGhAZDOzCtJTU8t@q@bWJADAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), 18 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```
{1<⍵:(⌊⍺÷⍵)∇⍵|⍺⋄⍵}
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=qza0edS71UrjUU/Xo95dh7cDOZqPOtqBVA2Q/6i7BciqBQA&f=TYqxEQAhDMN6T8EIcYD/ZCH2HwETGiqdJXO21QZoLv5wE1xTMJACkVlt1HWiH9tN@vrLDxE1T5VCxlMzYwM&i=AwA&r=tryapl&l=apl-dyalog-extended&m=train&n=f)

A dfn that takes the first number as the left argument and the second number as the right argument.

Answer (score 0):

## [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/)'s type system, 97 bytes

```typescript
//@ts-ignore
type M<A,B,T=[]>=A extends[...B,...infer I]?M<I,B,[...T,1]>:A extends[1]|[]?A:M<T,A>
```

[Try it at the TypeScript playground!](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTACBcGcFoEsHMB2B7ATgUwFDgJ4Ad0ACAWQB4BBAGgCFKAVAXgG0BdAPgfMPQA9x1EAE0hMAdONrjRsRADN0qQgEkWAfjJKalMeLqUAjOwBcXXvyEjDAH1aryRsnvJtMmEIQBiyZP0XBCdOiQ4IQAxgCGkEGuuASEAKqI4ag4pABy3HwCwoSIAK4AtgBGCpSEAPKZ5jn6rIQMhKxs9RVV2ZCEAN6EADYC8OAAFkaEGQC+hKqtI4nJqWllOqLlZYYusUSBwRRtFrmFJahl1Ls5+cUKzQ1ksykUbGW3qdRsbADcMfibQeD6LVvgUj6ACsZQALC53IRCAA9VTYL4BH4AJn+PyBAAZkWUAOyQ-zQuEIuIAgDMaO2yIxZWR+OhsPhGyRwTBFMB+n0qzphMZiIBwLZpAAnELcdyGcTvsEAGyCsGgwjy8VEoA)

I/O is unary numbers / tuples of 1s.

Modified from [my solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/263394) to [Division and remainder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/114003/division-and-remainder).

Answer (score 0):

**[T-SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-reference?view=sql-server-ver16) 77 bytes**

```
declare @x int = 88, @y int = 7, @z int
```

```
while @y > 1 BEGIN
select @z = @x/@y, @y = @x-(@z*@y)
set @x = @z
end
select @y
```

[Try it!](https://sqlfiddle.com/sql-server/online-compiler?id=399555d9-70e3-4389-9dca-957c17a46d9b)